# Twitter Widget appearing too wide on mobile

Tags: css, twitter

Having an issue with this site (http://loriveltri.com/) on mobile. Issue is the Twitter widget....which comes straight from Twitter, appears too wide (about 520px) on mobile devices. When I check in my browser and adjust, it's fine. Only on mobile does it burst out like this and it's odd. Any idea how I can fix this max-width issue from the CSS the widget produces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use !important in your css

```
.boxed-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media (max-width: 677px)
.span3 iframe {
  max-width: 300px !important;
}
```

Comment: That was great. Didn't even need the !important as it just worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add CSS specification for **small screen** 480px is for mobile divices

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {}
```

or try this and set your **width**

```
iframe#twitter-widget-0 {}
```